# How to get topOffset with a class named 'dropdown' in Angular

Tags: angular, dropdown, offset, popover

I need the same result in Angular as like jQuery/HTML.
Using jQuery, I'm getting the same topOffset value if I scroll or not.

```
// get the top offset of the dropdown (distance from top of the page)
var topOffset = $(".dropdown").offset().top;
```

For your information, in Angular I am using template variable with **@ViewChild**, but the topOffset value got changed and is not giving the same required result as like jQuery.

```
  @ViewChild('dp') dropdown: ElementRef
  functionName() {
     let topOffset = this.dropdown.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  }
```

Please let me know in the comment, what I have to do to achieve the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.top`
offsetTop is relative to it's place in the document, not relative to the view port

You can get offsetTop from the top of the document using this

```
 this.dropdown.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Comment: I have already used ".top", but it's not the required result.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is opensource, if you look for in github (this [link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/offset.js)) you see

```
offset: function( options ) {
    ...
    rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    win = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView;
    return {
        top: rect.top + win.pageYOffset,
        left: rect.left + win.pageXOffset
    };
 }
```

As you see you need add win.pageYOffset

So you can create a function

```
  getOffset(element:HTMLElement){
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const win = element.ownerDocument.defaultView;
        return {
            top: rect.top + win.pageYOffset,
            left: rect.left + win.pageXOffset
        };
  }
```

And use

```
this.offset= this.getOffset(this.dropdown.nativeElement)
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ocveoa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use offsetTop instead of getBoundingClientRect().top

```
 @ViewChild('dp') dropdown: ElementRef
  functionName() {
     let topOffset = this.dropdown.nativeElement.offsetTop;
  }
```

Check a simple sample here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6jmua2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html